# Unable to access cookies when posting from different site in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, cross-domain, razor-pages, samesite

I am experiencing troubles accessing cookie information when I get posted from a different site to our site.

I read the cookies this way

```
public static string GetCookie(HttpContext context, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return context.Request.Cookies[key];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{methodName} | Exception : {ex.Message} | StackTrace : {ex.StackTrace} | InnerException : {ex.InnerException}");
            }
        }
```

And save the cookies this way

```
public static void SetCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, int expiresInMinutes = 20)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    Secure = false,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(expiresInMinutes) 
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{methodName} | Exception : {ex.Message} | StackTrace : {ex.StackTrace} | InnerException : {ex.InnerException}");
            }
        }
```

Suppose my site is https://site1.com and I have redirected to a payment gateway https://pgateway.com, I am able to access the cookies when pgateway.com redirects using a GET request, but unable to access when pgateway.com is posting the data. The cookies have been already saved before the redirection itself.

I have added the following info. for CORS

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(); 

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.WithOrigins("https://pgateway.com").AllowAnyMethod()
    );
}
```

Please help me out regarding this concern. Thanks.

Comment: What's the SameSite setting on the cookies? There could be some cross-site issues here. Also "redirects using POST" is not technically correct, a redirect is always a GET. They are making a POST from the page to your back-end, it's not a redirect.

Comment: Yes.. The payment gateway is Posting the data. I tried to set SameSite to None, Strict and Lax, but still it doesn't work, but it works everytime when the data is sent via GET. I am new to CORS stuff. Does it matter to cookies if the method is GET or POST ?
PS : Edited the "redirects using POST"

Comment: What do your CORS settings look like? Do you use "AllowCredentials()" in the CORS policy?

Comment: @juunas ... Edited my question to accomodate the CORS config

Comment: I can see AllowCredentials() is not there :) Can you try adding it?

Comment: I made this change.... options => options.WithOrigins("https://pgateway.com").AllowCredentials() .... Its still not giving the cookie values...

Comment: Is that with SameSite = None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to the samesite attribute of the cookie. Try the following; the secure attribute is required.

```
public static void SetCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, int expiresInMinutes = 20)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    Secure = true,   // updated
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,  // added
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(expiresInMinutes) 
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{methodName} | Exception : {ex.Message} | StackTrace : {ex.StackTrace} | InnerException : {ex.InnerException}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.